# greasemonkey, jquery and $ being undefined -- chrome compatible

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a jquery wrapper which will allow new userscripts i'm writing to function alongside older ones, in both chrome and firefox, and run jquery. My former userscripts used Joan Piedra's method (http://joanpiedra.com/jquery/greasemonkey/) but this doesn't work in Chrome because Chrome doesn't support unsafewindow.

So I found Erik Vold's method for running jQuery in Chrome as well (http://erikvold.com/blog/index.cfm/2010/6/14/using-jquery-with-a-user-script), however it doesn't work at all in firefox alongside the existing userscripts.

I decided to try to adapt Erik's script to first search for jquery and then only insert the script tag if jquery is undefined. If jquery exists, it doesn't insert a jquery script tag, but just runs the jquery callback (in no conflict mode, because I expect this to be running on a page with scriptaculous as well.)

My issue (the first of many, I'm sure given the number of requirements I have) is in the if/else statement in addJQuery: in the else part of the statement (where the jquery object should not be 'undefined') the jquery object is still actually 'undefined' so I get the error that '$' is undefined when the callback runs.

Erik's original code attached an event listener to the loading of the jquery script but I don't know how to do this in the event jquery is already there but not necessarily loaded (I've tried attaching event listeners to the window, the document, document.head and document.body and nothing worked.)

I've also tried using window.setTimeout but I couldn't get it to repeat more than once, with the same results ($ is undefined.)

I will also mention that, in the case when I know jQuery isn't there to begin with, the script does successfully add the script tag, and I have attached the event listener to the script, and I still get the error that $ is undefined.

So I'm completely at a loss now. I can't detect jQuery, even when it seems I have, I can't run the code, and even when it seems I am, it still breaks.

```
function addJQuery(callback) {
if(typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){
    var libsrc = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js";
    var dochead = head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var jqscript = document.createElement("script");
    jqscript.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");    
    jqscript.setAttribute("src", libsrc);

    // append script tag as first element in the head 
    dochead.insertBefore(jqscript, head.childNodes[0]);

    jqscript.addEventListener('load', function(){
        var runscript = document.createElement("script");

        // force no conflict mode allowing $
        runscript.textContent = "jQuery.noConflict(); (function($) {   $(function() {" + callback.toString() +  "}); })(jQuery);";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(runscript);
        callback();
    }, false);
}
else{
    // jquery is still undefined?!?!?!?!
    var runscript = document.createElement("script");
    runscript.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");  

    // force no conflict mode allowing $
    runscript.textContent = "jQuery.noConflict(); (function($) {       $(function() {" + callback.toString() +  "}); })(jQuery);";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(runscript);
    callback();

}

}

function main() {
 alert($); // check if the dollar (jquery) function works
 alert($().jquery); // check jQuery version
}

// load jQuery and execute the main function
addJQuery(main);
```

Answer (score 0):

To solved the problem of $ is undefined you can do this, before all of your code:

```
function esperar() {

        if (typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') {

            // Si aún no se ha cargado, esperar un poco más

            window.setTimeout(esperar, 100);



        } 

        else {

            $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery.noConflict(true);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that method several times and haven't gotten it to work. Also I can't use unsafeWindow and have it run in Chrome, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I added the line `$ = jQ.noConflict(true);` to Erik Vold's script. This works for me!

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         jQuery For Chrome (A Cross Browser Example)
// @namespace    jQueryForChromeExample
// @include      *
// @author       Erik Vergobbi Vold & Tyler G. Hicks-Wright (modified)
// @description  This userscript is meant to be an example on how to use jQuery in a userscript on Google Chrome.
// ==/UserScript==

// loads jQuery with a callback when jQuery has loaded
function addJQuery(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js");
  script.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "$=jQuery.noConflict(true);(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function main() {
    // rest of code goes here
}

// load jQuery and execute the main function
addJQuery(main);
```